# C# mvc populate dropdownlist from class property get and set with defualt value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, dropdown

I'm working with  MVC, new stuff to me. I have the following ,

I want to fill drop-down list from class property get and set , i have   default value for this property

> MaximumNumberOfRooms

this property i want to populate it with drop-down .

```
 SessionHelper mysession = new SessionHelper(); //this line calling defualt values  

 public  class SessionHelper
 {
    public SessionHelper()
    {
          MaximumNumberOfRooms = 4;

    }
     public int MaximumNumberOfRooms
    {
        get { return(int)(HttpContext.Current.Session["MaximumNumberOfRooms"]); }
        set { HttpContext.Current.Session["MaximumNumberOfRooms"] = value; }
    }


 }
```

```html
          <p>Rooms</p>                            
          <select class="dropdown">
                 <option value="">1</option>
                 <option value="">2</option>
                 <option value="">3</option>
                 <option value="">4</option>
          </select>
```

this is my controller

```
public ActionResult Index( )
    {
        var model = new SessionHelper();


        return View();

    }
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: i want to fill drop-down list with value "4" that inside MaximumNumberOfRooms   property

Comment: Re-read my comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to pass model to the view:

```
public ActionResult Index( )
{
    var model = new SessionHelper();
    return View(model);
}
```

In view you should define model type if not defined:

```
@model SessionHelper
```

and iterate through a number of rooms:

Rooms

```
<select class="dropdown">
    @for(int i = 1; i <= Model.MaximumNumberOfRooms; i++)
    {
        <option value="@i">@i</option>
    }
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the controller to return the model:

```
public ActionResult Index( )
{
    var model = new SessionHelper();


    return View(model);

}
```

In the view, iterate the max number of rooms and set the selected one:

```
<p>Rooms</p>                            
<select class="dropdown">
    @for (var i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
         <option value="@i" @(i == Model.MaximumNumberOfRooms ? "selected" : "")>@i</option>
    }
</select>
```

Comment: I am not sure that it is good idea to always mark largest value as selected.

Comment: It's marking selected if the iterated index matched the MaxNumberOfRooms. not the largest number.

Comment: Well, then you hardcode number of iteration to 4. I am not sure that  you answer is correct anymore.

Comment: He has 4 options, 1 - 4. He wants to set the maximum number of rooms based on the session helper value. This iterates 4 times and adds those 4 options. It selects the one that matches. The hard-coded rooms list is what he wants. At least that's how the question reads to me. But English doesn't seem to be his first language so it's worded a little confusingly, but this seems to make sense in the context.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you want to use that model in your view then you need to send it to the view:

```
return View(model);
```

And of course add the corresponding model declaration at the top of the view:

```
@model SessionHelper
```

Now that you have the model available in your view, you can use it.  In this case I suppose you'd loop from 1 to the model value to output your markup.  Something like:

```
<select class="dropdown">
@for(var i = 1; i <= Model.MaximumNumberOfRooms; i++) {
     <option value="">@i</option>
}
</select>
```